# How is implemented the "Edit Details" view in the Contacts app?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiviewanimation

Is a UITableView set in "Edit Mode"?

If so:

1. Are several sections used? (Such as a section for phone and email?)
2. Does each section have a "Add row" row (i.e. "add phone"), so I can add a row at the end of each section?

[image]

Comment: This looks suspiciously like iOS7, if so the question may still be under an NDA.

Comment: The topic of the question is under Apple's NDA agreement and cannot at present be discussed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both questions can be answered with YES.

You can verify this by watching the animation when a new field is added or deleted. This is the usual insert and delete `UITableViewRowAnimation`. Also the deletion button on the left side of the row is the `UITableView` delete button.

Comment: Thanks, one last question: can I have a autocomplete popup opening while typing so I can suggest a list of names with the same initials? Can I have this for a row in such table?

Comment: Of course you can, you just have to create a custom `UITableViewCell` that provides that feature.